# Css navigation dropdown appearing on bottom left on hover

Tags: html, css, nav

I have a navigation menu in PHP,HTML and CSS 
but there are some issues with the dropdown code
The menu is on the top and has child items and on hover it show sub menus 
But when i Hover the sub menu items appear on the bottom on the bottom left which is looking bad.
How can i add a drop down on this code ?

HTML CODE

```
<div class="header">
<div class="logo"><a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo_chrome.gif" alt="Logo Chrome" /></a></div>
<div class="navi">

<ul>
<li><?PHP if($pagename == "index"){ ?><a href="index.php" class="home active"> </a><?PHP }else {?> <a href="index.php" class="home"> </a> <?PHP } ?></li>

<li><?PHP if($pagename == "service"){ ?><a href="service.php" class="service active"> </a><?PHP }else {?> <a href="service.php" class="service"> </a> <?PHP } ?>

<ul>


       <li>         <a href="#">Service one</a>       </li>    
          <li>      <a href="#">Service three</a></li>
             <li>    <a href="#">Service four</a></li>
   </ul>                     



</li>
<li><?PHP if($pagename == "contacts"){ ?><a href="contacts.php" class="contacts active"> </a><?PHP }else {?> <a href="contacts.php" class="contacts"> </a> <?PHP } ?></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

//  CSS

```
body img{ margin:0; padding:0; border:0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#737373; }
UL, OL { margin:0; padding:0; list-style: none;}
li { margin:0; padding:0; list-style-type:none;}

A { color:#00558e; text-decoration:none; border: none;}
/*A:visited{ text-decoration:none; color:#;}*/
A:hover {color:#9ed101; text-decoration:none; outline:none; border:0;}
/*A:active { text-decoration:none; color:#;}*/
A:focus {outline:none;}
.clr {clear: both;}
/*LAYOUT*/
#wrap{ margin:0 auto; padding:0; width:996px;}
.header{ margin:0; padding:0px 10px 0 10px; width:976px; height:92px; float:left; }
.logo{ margin:0; padding:0; width:152px; height:89px; float:left; border-bottom:red 0px solid;}
.navi{ margin:0; padding:15px 0 0 0;  width:712px; height:71px; float:right; }
.navi ul{ margin:0; padding:0; width:712px; float:left;}
.navi ul li{ margin:0; padding:0; display:block; float:left;}
.navi ul li a.home{ margin:0; padding:0; display:block; float:left; width:50px; height:56px; background:url(../images/home.gif) no-repeat top;}
.navi ul li a.home:hover{ margin:0; padding:0; display:block; float:left; width:50px; height:56px; background-position:bottom;}
.navi ul li a.home.active{ margin:0; padding:0; display:block; float:left; width:50px; height:56px; background-position:bottom;}






/*Custom CSS for Sub Menu*/
nav ul li > ul:before {
    content: "";
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 9px 9px 9px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #2C3E50 transparent;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    top: 5px;
}

nav ul li > ul { position: absolute; left: 14px; top: 80%; padding-top: 13px; background: none; width: 150px; z-index: -9999; opacity: 0; -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-out; }
nav ul li:hover > ul { display: block; z-index: 100; opacity: 1; top: 95%; }

nav ul li > ul li:first-child { border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; padding-top: 3px; }
nav ul li > ul li:last-child { border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px; }
nav ul li > ul li { padding: 0 3px 3px; background: #2C3E50; width: 100%; }
nav ul li > ul li a .service{ display: block; padding: 6px 9px; border-radius: 2px; font-size: 14px; }
nav ul li > ul li:hover > a { color: #FFF; background: #3498DB; }
nav ul li > ul li.active > a { color: #FFF; background: #2980B9; }



/* SUB SUB MENU */
nav ul li > ul li > ul:before {
    content: "";
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 9px 9px 9px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #2C3E50 transparent;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 15px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
}

nav ul li > ul li > ul { top: 0; left: 90%; padding: 0; padding-left: 13px; -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-out; }
nav ul li > ul li:hover > ul { display: block; opacity: 1; z-index: 100; top: 0; left: 100%; }
```

Comment: try to produce a demo please, so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: How should i do that because the menu items contains images and if i paste the code in JSFiddle it does shows the images . heres the screenshot how it looks like .http://awesomescreenshot.com/0e842ckrbe

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fbk1t1hz/ is the entire code for css and the html

Comment: You can try to add the images as external resources in the panel on the left.

Answer (score 0):

try this out in your css

```
.navi ul li{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: make changes to the following css - nav ul li > ul{top:100%;left:0;}

Comment: Thanks @creativeNitish I did you what you said and it worked for the menu part but it is overlapping to image banner . I mean the image banner is in front and menu is in the back.Sorry to bother you.http://imgur.com/kojNvYi

Comment: give image banner the following css: 'z-index:-9999'